# Launching the application on startup before starting Desktop GUI

Tags: command-line, bash, autostart, startup-applications, startup-disk-creator

I am trying to launch an application(for example browser) on startup. **I want this to be launched before Desktop GUI appears.**

1. I tried gnome-session-properties and adding the application. But it opens the desktop and then opens my application.
2. I also tried

   ```bsh
   sudo vi /etc/rc.local
   ```

   and writing shell script:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   firefox
   exit 0
   ```

   and then `chmod +x` , and rebooting the system.
3. Also tried `mystartup.sh` and creating `mystartup` service in `systemctl`, and rebooting the system.

How can I achieve this? Launching application as soon as I power on the Ubuntu PC.

Comment: you cannot launch an X application without the X server running, Gnome in this case

Comment: @GiorgosSaridakis That could be posted as the answer to this question, just expanded a bit.

Comment: If you want a faster desktop environment you can also use the [i3](https://i3wm.org) window manager.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to run an X application (a graphics application) before the graphics user interface (first logical outcome of the X server) comes up, I am taking Mark Kirby's advise and expanding my comment though.

Your Ubuntu's X server is the dock onto which all graphical applications, mouse events, everything a modern OS carries are connected to. It's not possible to have an app with GUI without it's carrier, the X server. The desktop GUI is the first logical conclusion of X server startup. It has been irreversibly programmed this way.

If you give some clues as to why you are trying to do this in the first place, maybe the community will give you more assistance.

Cheer up, Ubuntu desktop GUI is very advanced and efficient.

Comment: I am creating Application GUI in QT creator. I m using ubuntu 18.04 on raspberry Pi 4. as soon as Pi is switched on, I want my application to run and open GUI that i have created.

Comment: QT creator needs an X server to attach itself on